# Can the mlr package be used to make predictions based on data from a panel study?

Tags: r, supervised-learning, mlr, longitudinal

I am planning to do a supvervised machine learning project where I use data from a longitudinal study (panel study). The goal is to use the 2004 and 2009 predictors to predict the 2014 outcomes. I have now done a first data-preprocessing and the data frame looks like the following in a highly abbreviated form:

```
data_ml <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c(
      201,
      203,
      602,
      901,
      1202,
      1501,
      1601,
      1602,
      1603,
      201,
      203,
      602,
      901,
      1202,
      1501,
      1601,
      1602,
      1603,
      201,
      203,
      602,
      901,
      1202,
      1501,
      1601,
      1602,
      1603
    ),
    Studyyear = c(
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2009,
      2009,
      2009,
      2009,
      2009,
      2009,
      2009,
      2009,
      2009,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014
    ),
    Gender = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,
               2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1),
    Predictor1 = c(6,
                   5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6,
                   4, 6, 4, 3, 3),
    Predictor2 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                   2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2),
    Predictor3 = c(0,
                   6, 1, 6, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, 6, 1, 6, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6,
                   0, 0, 4, 1, 1),
    Outcome1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
                 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
    Outcome2 = c(0,
                 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-27L)
)
```

Until now, my prediction projects did not include the time dimension (see data_ml: "Studyyear"). So I could just create a task and then make the prediction with the "mlr" package as follows:

```
library(mlr)
task <- makeClassifTask(data = data_ml, target = 'Outcome1', positive = '1')
measures = list(acc, auc, tpr, tnr, f1)
resampling_MC <- makeResampleDesc(method = 'Subsample', iters = 500) 
learner_logreg <- makeLearner('classif.logreg', predict.type = 'prob')
benchmark_MC <- benchmark(learners = learner_logreg, tasks = task, resamplings = resampling_MC, measures = measures)
```

Is it still possible to work with the "mlr" package with such a data frame as above and include the time dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the [mlr3forecasting package](https://mlr3temporal.mlr-org.com/index.html), see the example [here](https://mlr3temporal.mlr-org.com/articles/mlr3forecasting.html). The package isn't on CRAN yet though and still experimental, so you'll have to install it from Github (instructions on the package website) and things may not work as expected.